# SVG background - fixed height

Tags: css, svg

I have a question to the SVG format. I created the background as you can see in the attached screenshot.

When I have a screen resolution over 920px its fine.
But when I check the responsive views, the blue svg image decreases the height value by deacreasing the windows.

My goal is, to keep the wave structure and the height, because there should be a logo on top of the background.
But when I decrease the window the logo is no longer in the blue wave.

A fixed height in the svg data is also bad, because we don't keep the complete wave structure.

How is it possible?

Do I need a parent div with background-position: cover?

[image: Screenshot]

Code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#230A59" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,288L48,272C96,256,192,224,288,192C384,160,480,128,576,133.3C672,139,768,181,864,192C960,203,1056,181,1152,165.3C1248,149,1344,139,1392,133.3L1440,128L1440,0L1392,0C1344,0,1248,0,1152,0C1056,0,960,0,864,0C768,0,672,0,576,0C480,0,384,0,288,0C192,0,96,0,48,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>'
```

Comment: I don't really understand you. Do you mean screen width over 920px? I just pasted your code into a codepen and actually it's just the blue section. And it seems to scale and shrink responsively - full width, no distortion. I built a codepen with a container for the SVG - if this is what you mean I'll post it as the answer, but I'm clutching at straws. https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/oNXxZPO

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding. The shrinking is the problem. When you decrease the window the size of the wave shrinks. I want to keep the size same as before.

Comment: Ok. You can’t keep the same height on a smaller screen without fixing the height - and then you’d lose the aspect ratio. You could serve a svg for mobile that is more suitable for portrait screens, and a landscape one for desktop. But I’m not 100% sure what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: @Doughballs thanks.I think your answer fits my needs. I thought it is possible to have a variable height and something pulls the height along a specific vh automatically. Imagine in the blue area is a logo. When you shrink the blue area, the logo will reach the orange area on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible.  You can't keep the aspect ratio, the complete wave structure, and the height.  The best you can do is two out of three of those things.

#### Aspect ratio + complete wave

```css
svg {
  background-color: #fd490d;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#230A59" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,288L48,272C96,256,192,224,288,192C384,160,480,128,576,133.3C672,139,768,181,864,192C960,203,1056,181,1152,165.3C1248,149,1344,139,1392,133.3L1440,128L1440,0L1392,0C1344,0,1248,0,1152,0C1056,0,960,0,864,0C768,0,672,0,576,0C480,0,384,0,288,0C192,0,96,0,48,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>
```

#### Aspect ratio + height

```css
svg {
  background-color: #fd490d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"><path fill="#230A59" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,288L48,272C96,256,192,224,288,192C384,160,480,128,576,133.3C672,139,768,181,864,192C960,203,1056,181,1152,165.3C1248,149,1344,139,1392,133.3L1440,128L1440,0L1392,0C1344,0,1248,0,1152,0C1056,0,960,0,864,0C768,0,672,0,576,0C480,0,384,0,288,0C192,0,96,0,48,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>
```

#### Complete wave + height

```css
svg {
  background-color: #fd490d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path fill="#230A59" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,288L48,272C96,256,192,224,288,192C384,160,480,128,576,133.3C672,139,768,181,864,192C960,203,1056,181,1152,165.3C1248,149,1344,139,1392,133.3L1440,128L1440,0L1392,0C1344,0,1248,0,1152,0C1056,0,960,0,864,0C768,0,672,0,576,0C480,0,384,0,288,0C192,0,96,0,48,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>
```